# Haskell: Find k missing numbers from a sorted list [1..n]

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I am learning Haskell and FP in general and decided this was an interesting problem to try and solve.  The algorithm I am attempting is to use a variation of quickselect to count the length of two sublists split on a pivot, and if the length difference is 1 then use the difference of sums approach to find the missing number.  If greater than 1 then I recursively drill into the sublist.

I feel like I am pretty close to a working solution here but there are a few fringe cases that don't seem to work well.  Where n is smaller than 100, I sometimes I have certain missing numbers that are missed seemingly randomly and when n is sufficiently small compared to k missing numbers I sometimes get a runtime exception.  For large sets of n, this runs correctly seemingly.  I must be missing something simple.

Any thoughts?  A simple guard that I missed?

```
findMissingNumber :: (Ord k, Integral k, Enum k) => [k] -> [k]
findMissingNumber [] = []
findMissingNumber xs = ( sum' [(head xs)..(last xs)] - sum' xs ) : []


findMissingNumbs :: [Int] -> [Int]
findMissingNumbs [] = []
findMissingNumbs xs =
  let shouldBeLength = length [(head xs)..(last xs)]
      pivot = round $ fromIntegral (shouldBeLength) / 2
      pivotValue = xs !! (pivot - 1)
      lower = filter (< pivotValue) xs
      upper = filter (>= pivotValue) xs
      lowerMissingCount 
        | lower == [] = 0
        | (length lower) == 1 = 0
        | otherwise = (length [(head lower)..(last lower)]) - (length lower)
      upperMissingCount 
        | upper == [] = 0
        | (length upper) == 1 = 0
        | otherwise = (length [(head upper)..(last upper)]) - (length upper)
      missingLowerValues 
        | (lowerMissingCount) == 1 = findMissingNumber (lower)
        | (lowerMissingCount) > 1 = findMissingNumbs (lower)
        | (lowerMissingCount) == 0 = []
        | otherwise = []
      missingUpperValues
        | (upperMissingCount) == 1 = findMissingNumber (upper)
        | (upperMissingCount) > 1 = findMissingNumbs (upper)
        | (upperMissingCount) == 0 = []
        | otherwise = []
  in
     missingLowerValues ++ [] ++ missingUpperValues

sum' :: (Num k) => [k] -> k
sum' xs = foldl' (+) 0 xs

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a list size: "
  listSize <- readLn
  intToRemove <- sequence $ replicate 5 $ randomRIO (1, (listSize :: Int))
  putStrLn $ "Int to remove is: " ++ show intToRemove
  let defaultList = [1..(listSize :: Int)]
  let missingNumbers = findMissingNumbs $ (filter (not . (`elem` intToRemove)) defaultList)
  putStrLn $ "The missing number is " ++ show missingNumbers
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you're trying to solve? Why not a linear search through the list, since it's already sorted?

Comment: @crockeea I was wanting an algo that was better than O(n) and I arbitraily picked the problem because it seemed like an interesting recursive approach to do in FP

Comment: Your implementation is still O(n) if you are computing the sum or length of lists like `[(head xs)..(last xs)]`.

Comment: @chepner Really? The function head and last in Haskell is O(n)? I am not saying you are wrong, like I said I am pretty new to Haskell and just doing this as a learning exercise.

Comment: For some reason, you are creating a list of size `last xs - head xs + 1`, and then computing its length. Why not just use the formula? Of course calling `length lower` is still O(n).

Comment: @maple_shaft `last` is O(n) (it has to walk all the way to the end of the list), but even it it wasn't, both `sum` and `length` are strict in their argument, so the list would need to be constructed in its entirety.

Comment: @chepner regardless I can definitely optimize it later if I want to. That really wasnt my question.

Comment: Your recursion seems to assume that the largest value in `lower` will always be `pivotValue - 1` (and similarly for the smallest value in `upper`), which will cause you to omit missing numbers that are adjacent to `pivotValue`. However, there's little point in fixing this, because it's never going to be O(n) as long as `length` is not an O(1) operation.

Comment: @chepner I am passing around these lists when it is probably better to pass indexes and look to the list for values. I  dont need to call length I suppose, I can figure that out with some arithmetic.

Comment: @maple_shaft the first thing you should do is understand what a list is (it's not an array, but a recursive algebraic data type), and then the time complexity of the prelude list functions will be obvious, without looking at the implementation. As for debugging, you might have fun playing with [quickcheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) as a debugging aid; once it gives you a minimal failing case, the next step is to step through the algorithm with a pen and paper or in your head until you see the bug.

Comment: @chepner I think that view is too narrow. Lists are a convenient syntax for prototyping an algorithm that can later be converted to e.g. arrays, where all the operations that need to be done in O(1) can be. So why not write up an answer with the details needed to fix this algorithm, since that's already an interesting problem in itself?